# (Android) Can't See Flurry Logs

Tags: android, flurry

I'm trying to implement `Flurry Analytics` on my app and here's the log for the session.

```
04-17 07:31:10.292: D/FlurryAgent(5431): Initializing Flurry session
04-17 07:31:10.311: D/FlurryAgent(5431): New session
04-17 07:31:10.681: I/FlurryAgent(5431): loading persistent data: /data/data/com.jekkusan.myapp/files/.flurryagent.4b5cc4c4
04-17 07:31:10.691: D/FlurryAgent(5431): Loading API key: ****************Z8R4
04-17 07:31:10.691: D/FlurryAgent(5431): Loading phoneId: AND21ed71f9f324aa40
04-17 07:31:10.691: D/FlurryAgent(5431): Loading session reports
04-17 07:31:10.691: D/FlurryAgent(5431): Persistent file loaded
04-17 07:31:10.731: D/FlurryAgent(5431): generating report
04-17 07:31:10.761: D/FlurryAgent(5431): Sending report to: http://data.flurry.com/aap.do
04-17 07:31:20.001: D/FlurryAgent(5431): Report successful
04-17 07:31:20.001: D/FlurryAgent(5431): Done sending initial agent report
```

I'm not seeing any change on my app's dashboard. I already waited for so long, around 1 hour but still no change at all. How am I suppose to fix this?

Also, I am calling `FlurryAgent.onStartSession(context, "APP_KEY")` on my `Activity`'s `onStart()` and `FlurryAgent.onEndSession(context)` on `onStop()`.

Thanks!

Comment: you are doing everyhting right, but it may take more than 1 hour..

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I'll report back here later, after 2 to 3 hours, and see if it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I was 6 hours but no logs yet. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code is working, there's no problem here. I just have to wait for several hours to see the changes on the server.